# DDS NBFM transmitter design

Tags: frequency, modulation, dds

As a design exercise I'm trying to come up with a design for NBFM. I'd like to stick with digital domain as much as possible, since that's what I know best. I'm familiar with RF enough to know that I know nothing of it... I did design a 868 MHz telemetry transmitter board using a Micrel RF chip almost ten years ago, and it worked without problems and to the best of my knowledge is still in production with the company I worked for at the time. But that was only following Micrel's app note...

So my idea is to use a DDS chip such as AD9832 to generate narrow band FM signal centered around 10.7 MHz. Deviation should be around 10 kHz, enough for human voice. I would then use a digitally controlled PLL along with a mixer to up the frequency to my target which is around 450 MHz. Is the AD9832 a suitable choice for this? From reading the datasheet it contains a 25 MSPS 10-bit DAC and can accept serial data up to 20 MHz. Therefore I think it should be able to do the 10.7 MHz signal.

Am I on the rigth track with this? Any pointers for a possible receiver end IC?

Comment: Your deviation will grow by 45 times - do you realize that? 10 kHz deviation needn't be related to the base bandwidth by the way. You can have deviation much less than the required base bandwidth.

Comment: Is it because of the mixer going from 10 to 450 MHz? So should I only modulate at 220 Hz at the IF frequency? If I then decide to make the final RF frequency adjustable I need to also take into account the deviation frequency? Something does not sound right here...

Comment: Well, it's how I read your proposed solution. You say you are using a PLL and that will multiply up all frequencies including deviations. But, then again you say you are using a mixer so, which is it. Better still, add a diagram.

Comment: My intention is to provide the RF upmixing frequency using a digitally controlled PLL. For example, use the PLL to generate 439.3 MHz and mix that with 10.7 MHz to get the final 450 MHz. Then filter out the unwanted products.

Comment: @Andyaka "A PLL along with a mixer" sounds like the PLL is generating the carrier frequency for the mixer

Comment: @user253751 I think that suggestion needs confirming by the OP.

Comment: The PLL is generating the local oscillator signal for the mixer. Pardon my lack of proper terms.

Comment: Hi guys. A week has passed but I have not had any answers to my actual question. Do you think AD9832 could be used for the purpose outlined in my question?